# Why do I get duplicates in my textbox using system speech?

Tags: c#, winforms, speech-to-text

[image]

Why do I get duplicates? If I change

```
textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + " " + e.Result.Text.ToString();
```

to

```
textBox1.Text = e.Result.Text.ToString();
```

then the textbox will not keep the old information. Is there a way to fix this?

Here is my script:

```
SpeechSynthesizer sSynth = new SpeechSynthesizer();
PromptBuilder pBuilder = new PromptBuilder();
SpeechRecognitionEngine sRecogEn = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Choices slist = new Choices();
    slist.Add(new string[] {"start", "start listening"});
    Grammar gr = new Grammar(new GrammarBuilder(slist));
    try{
        sRecogEn.RequestRecognizerUpdate();
        sRecogEn.LoadGrammar(gr);
        sRecogEn.SpeechRecognized += sRecogEn_SpeechRecognized;
        sRecogEn.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
        sRecogEn.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
    }
    catch {
        return;            
    }
}

private void btnSpeakText_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pBuilder.ClearContent();
    pBuilder.AppendText(textBox1.Text);
    sSynth.Speak(pBuilder);
}

private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Text = string.Empty;
    btnStart.Enabled = false;
    btnStop.Enabled = true;
    Choices slist = new Choices();
    slist.Add(new string[] {"hello world", "step on the cat", "this is a test", "this is cool", "it works", "exit","stop listening", "new search", "stop"});
    Grammar gr = new Grammar(new GrammarBuilder(slist));
    try
    {
        sRecogEn.RequestRecognizerUpdate();
        sRecogEn.LoadGrammar(gr);
        sRecogEn.SpeechRecognized += sRecogEn_SpeechRecognized;
        sRecogEn.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
        sRecogEn.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
    }
     catch
     {
        return;
     }
 }
 private void sRecogEn_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
 {

    if ((e.Result.Text == "start") || (e.Result.Text == "start listening"))
    {
       btnStart.PerformClick();
       textBox1.Text = string.Empty;
    }
        else if ((e.Result.Text == "stop") || (e.Result.Text == "stop listening"))
        {
            btnStop.PerformClick();
            textBox1.Text = string.Empty;
        }
        else if ((e.Result.Text == "stop") || (e.Result.Text == "stop listening"))
        {
            sRecogEn.RecognizeAsyncStop();
            btnStart.Enabled = true;
            textBox1.Text = string.Empty;
        }
        else if (e.Result.Text == "new search")
        {
            textBox1.Text = string.Empty;
        }
        else if (e.Result.Text == "exit")
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }
    else
    {
        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + " " + e.Result.Text.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: what if you did textBox1.Text += e.Result.Text.ToString();

Comment: @box86rowh this gives me duplicates without a space

Answer (score 0):

You have added your eventhandler twice: once at Form1_Load and then a second time at btnStart_Click.

Event handlers are in the end delegates and these allow adding the same function more than once. If this happens, the function is called for every time it has been added.

Comment: I use the event handler in the `form_load` to initialize the speech-to-text without having to click the button. It will still duplicate if or when I remove it.

Comment: Your event handler seems to be correct. However, I don't know what the other functions of your engine do. Could the problem be related to doing the same (other) initialization twice?

Comment: Obviously, your event handler is called twice - if we do not manage to find out why, maybe we could work around it: Keep a pointer to the event and if the next event comes in, compare on equality - if true, just ignorer the event. If you still get double entries, then the event is probably generated twice. Then the source of the trouble might be in the speech engine.